# angular http.get not working

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, http-get

This is my service TS file:

```
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class ListService {

constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseURL: string) {}

public getAllLists(): Observable<ListModel[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + 'api/List/LoadLists').map(resp => resp.json());
}

}

export interface ListModel {
ListID: number;
ListType: string;
ListValue: string;
ListOrder: number;
}
```

And this is my component TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ListModel, ListService } from '../shared/list/list.service';

@Component({
selector: 'job-post',
templateUrl: './job-post.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./job-post.component.scss'],
providers: [ListService]
})

export class JobPostComponent implements OnInit {

private lists: ListModel[];
private listService: ListService;

constructor(listService: ListService) {
    this.listService = listService;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.listService.getAllLists()
        .subscribe(lists => this.lists = lists);
    console.log(this.lists);
}

}
```

In my ngOnInit event, this.lists comes back as undefined in the console statement, and if I hover on it in the "subscribe" part, it says "illegal return statement". However, Chrome says that the "http.get" itself returned properly and I can see the data at that point, so I know the controller method is okay.

I briefly had this working from the component TS file itself, but I figured it was better to separate it out into a service file since I'll need the lists from several places.

As far as I can tell, I've followed all the tutorials properly, but clearly I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Http request is async. You need to write console.log in subscribe.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.listService.getAllLists()
  .subscribe(lists => {
    this.lists = lists;
    console.log(this.lists);
  }
}
```

Also you need to use [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule) in you app. [HttpModule](https://angular.io/api/http/HttpModule) is deprecated.

Comment: The error occurs within the subscribe, so "this.lists" would still be undefined regardless of that. Also, I don't have anything another than Http available, I'm guessing you're referring to a more recent version of Angular than what my project is using.

Comment: I think the issue is my misunderstanding of when "this.lists" is actually available. I see what you mean about putting the console log call inside the "subscribe".